# Simple Pie on Wordpress.org trying to Format Output

Tags: php, wordpress, simplepie

I'm using the following code that I found on a wordpress.org help site.  I'm trying to customize it for my blog.  The goal is to grab my yahoo pipes aggregated feed and display it on a page on my wordpress.org blog.

### The cache code is not working because the output has not updated since yesterday.  I'm a novice at best when it comes to code and my guess is that I've got bad coding.  Thanks for any help.

```
    <h2><?php _e( 'AUSTIN TEXAS REAL ESTATE NEWS', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></h2>

    <?php // Get RSS Feed(s)
    include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php' );

// Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source.
    $rss = fetch_feed('http://feeds.feedburner.com/AustinRealEstateNewsInformation');

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : // Checks that the object is created correctly

// Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 25. 
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity( 25 ); 

// Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );

//set cache duration
    function return_1800( $seconds )
{
  // change the default feed cache recreation period to 30 minutes
  return 1800;
}

    add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'return_1800' );
    $feed = fetch_feed( $feed_url );
    remove_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'return_1800' );

    endif;
?>

<ul>
    <?php if ( $maxitems == 0 ) : ?>
        <li><?php _e( 'No items', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink. ?>
        <?php foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>"
                    <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?>.
<?php printf( __( '.%s', 'my-text-domain' ), $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a') ); ?>.
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```